# Weird vertical spacing within paragraph using multicol within tcolorbox

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol, tcolorbox

The basic idea would be to put a caption next to an image and center it vertically. I tried this within a `tcolorbox` environment since it's being used on a poster. I'm not sure, how much the `tcolorbox` frame matters, but I kept it as container here.

The idea would have been to put the picture into one column and the caption in the other, which should be offset using a `\vspace` command. As shown below, the code places the vertical space between the first and second line of the text and not above the first line (where it would be in the code).

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[boxsep=-1mm]
\begin{multicols}{2} % also tried unbalanced multicols*
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
    \draw (0,0) -- (5,4);
    \draw (5,0) -- (0,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{0.5cm} % this command causes strange vertical spacing
Figure aption. Weird vertical spacing between 1st and 2nd line, when using \textbackslash vspace command.
\end{multicols}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

For comparison, you can see two images, showing the effect of the `\vspace` command:

[image: correct behavior without vspace command]
[image: weird vertical spacing when using vspace command]

Is there a way to circumvent this? Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: it is a feature. `\vspace`, if used as here in horizontal mode adds the space after the paragraph has been broken into lines after the current line. a tikzpicture is just like a big letter and is part of the paragraph, it is not a display environment like a list which is set in vertical mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to leave the `horizontal` mode first, i.e. use an empty line, then issue `\vspace{0.5cm}`, if really needed.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[boxsep=-1mm]
\begin{multicols}{2} % also tried unbalanced multicols*
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
    \draw (0,0) -- (5,4);
    \draw (5,0) -- (0,4);
\end{tikzpicture}



% this command causes strange vertical spacing
\vspace{0.5cm}
Figure caption. No weird vertical spacing between 1st and 2nd line, when using \textbackslash vspace command.
\end{multicols}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you use `tcolorbox` there's no need for `multicol` environment, because `tcolorbox` already divides every box in `upper` and `lower` parts, which can be placed side by side.

Probably the easiest way to obtain OP's desired result is `\tcbsidebyside` box (present since 2015-11-20 version) which need `xparse` tcolorboxlibrary. This command already divides the box in two equal columns and the contents is vertically centered:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[skins,xparse]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\tcbsidebyside[notitle,lower separated=false]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
    \draw (0,0) -- (5,4);
    \draw (5,0) -- (0,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
}{%
Figure caption. Weird vertical spacing between 1st and 2nd line, when using \textbackslash vspace command.
}
\end{document}
```

[image]